# Bounding number of solutions of a congruence

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $d$ be a positive integer. Let $f(d,a)$ be the number of values of $x$ in $[1,d]$ such that $$x^{a}\equiv 1\pmod{d}.$$ I wanted to know if for some $0<\epsilon<1$, we can prove the following bound on the sum $$\sum_{i\mid\lambda(d)}\frac{f(d,i)}{i}\ll \lambda(d)^{\epsilon}$$ where $\lambda(d)$ is Carmichael's lambda function for almost all $d$. I found a resemblance of my question with Theorem 6 in this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2483003_Average_Multiplicative_Orders_of_Elements_Modulo_n) but couldn't translate those results to my setting.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: If $d=p_1\ldots p_k$ is a product of $k$ distinct primes and $i=2$ we get $f(d,2)=2^k$ and $\lambda(d)$ is lcm of numbers $p_i-1$, can not it be smaller than $2^k$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Sorry, I don't undertand your comment. Could you be more precise.

Comment: What exactly is not clear?

Comment: @FedorPetrov you are right. It has been proven that $\lambda(n)$ can take values as low as $(\log n)^{(\log\log\log n)}$ which would justify what you said. However, it is known that $\lambda(n)$ is quite large in a sequence of density 1 so I would edit my question.